# If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, show that there exists a point $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f(a) + f(b) = 2f(c)$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, show that there exists a point $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f(a) + f(b) = 2f(c)$.

This a problem on continuity. I tried but unable to start and solve the problem. How to solve it.

Comment: Cauchy's Mean Value theorem should do, I feel...

Comment: Hint: $\frac{f(a) + f(b)}{2}$ is in between the values $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. What does this imply? (edit: as noted below, we need $f(a) \neq f(b)$)

Comment: You have to assume $f(a) \neq f(b)$ or change your claim to $c \in [a,b]$. Otherwise $f(x) = x^2$, $(a,b) = (-1,1)$ provides a counterexample.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz What is the problem with $f(a)=f(b)$, I don't understand. In your example,  $f(-1)=f(1)$ then what actually you want to indicate? Please!!!

Comment: In my example $f(c) < 1$ for all $c \in (a,b)$, thus it is impossible to have $f(c) = \frac{f(-1)+f(1)}{2}$ (which is $1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the intermediate value theorem, for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\min(f(a), f(b)) < y < \max(f(a), f(b))$ there exists $x \in (a, b)$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Hence let $k = \dfrac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$.
If $f(a) \neq f(b)$, you know that $\min(f(a), f(b)) < k < \max(f(a), f(b))$. Thus by the mean value theorem, there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $f(c) = k$. Hence $2f(c) = 2k = 2\dfrac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} = f(a) + f(b)$, as required.

As M. Miśkiewicz pointed out in his comment, this requires $f(a) \neq f(b)$, and if they're equal your claim is not true.

Comment: How will it be affected if F is from N to N and is a bijection?

Comment: Are you wondering if it is true that there exist $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ so that for any $c\in\mathbb{N}$, $F(a)+F(b) = 2F(c)$, given that $F:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is a bijection? This is true because $2F(c)$ is a natural number greater than $1$, and every natural number greater than $1$ can be written as a sum of two natural numbers.

Comment: what I forgot to mention is a<c<b Now even it is true that we can find F(a) and F(b) but how do we prove that there is 'c' such that a<c<b and F(a) +F(b) =2F(c)

Comment: This is an entirely separate question so you should ask it separately with all of the required information. That way other people can answer it too.